# How to tweak nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have routes like this:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users, :only => :index do
    resources :skills, :only => :index
  end
end
resources :skills
```

In this case I got:

```
admin_user_skills GET /admin/users/:user_id/skills(.:format)
{:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/skills"}
```

How to change nested route in order to point to SkillsController instead of Admin::SkillsController? I'd like to have this:

```
admin_user_skills GET  /admin/users/:user_id/skills(.:format)
{:action=>"index", :controller=>"skills"}
```

Interesting thing - if we have no Admin::SkillsController, it will use SkillsController automatically, but only in development.

Answer (score 1):

Using `namespace` in routes implies to have special directory for "namespaced" controllers, admin in your case. But if you use `scope` instead you have what you need:

```
scope '/admin' do
  resources :users, :only => :index do
    resources :skills, :only => :index
  end
end
```